# I can't seem to figure out how to update tkinter labels

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a script to accept an image, then process the image and put a grid over it. I haven't merged the script that modifies the image yet. I'm trying to put a front end on this, I'm planning on publishing the script in a DnD facebook group for others to use to overlay grids onto their battlemaps. I can't seem to have the GUI update the labels which display the pixel length of the image the user selects.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import imageGrid
    import sys
    from PIL import *
    from PIL import Image





    root= tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    iWidth = tk.StringVar()
    iHeight = tk.StringVar()
    class pinger(tk.Tk):


def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.initialize()
    

def initialize(self):        
    self.grid()
    button = tk.Button(self,text="exit",command=lambda: closeProgram())
    button.grid(column=3,row=9)
    buttonOpen = tk.Button(self, text="Select an Image", command= lambda: openExplorer()
                           )
    buttonOpen.grid(column=2, row=2)
    labelSig = tk.Label(self, text='By Johnathan Keith, 2020. Ver 1.0')
    labelSig.grid(column=3,row=10)
    labelImgWidth = tk.Label(self, textvariable=iWidth)
    labelImgWidth.grid(column=2,row=3)
    labelStaticImg= tk.Label(self, text="Width of image, in pixels: ")
    labelStaticImg.grid(column=1,row=3)
    labelStaticHeight= tk.Label(self, text="Height of image, in pixels: ")
    labelStaticHeight.grid(column=3,row=3)
    labelImgHeight = tk.Label(self, textvariable=iHeight)
    labelImgHeight.grid(column=4,row=3)
    labelWidth = tk.Label(self, text='Enter the width of the grid, in pixels.')
    labelWidth.grid(column=4,row=2)
    labelDisclaim = tk.Label(self, text='Currently only works with jpegs')
    labelDisclaim.grid(column=2, row=1)

def openFile(imagefilename):
    Img = Image.open(imagefilename)
    height, width = Img.size
    iHeight.set(height)
    iWidth.set(width)
```

```
def closeProgram():
    app.destroy()
    sys.exit()
def openExplorer():
    app.filename= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select an Image", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"),("all files", "*.*")))
    if app.filename:
       print(app.filename)
       pinger.openFile(app.filename)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = pinger(None)
    app.title('Image Gridder')
    app.minsize(height=680,width=480)
    app.mainloop()
```

I've been searching through other SE questions and none of them seemed to work with the way my code is written. I'm trying to update the StringVar()'s iWidth and iHeight which will eventually allow the user to specify how they want the grid to overlay the image. I've tried moving them all over the code, in and out of the class, and nothing works. Also, StackExchange kinda butchered the indentation, so don't mind that.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't blame Stackoverflow for indentation errors, they are a sign you did something wrong when pasting and formatting the code.

Comment: Please describe what this code is doing. Is it throwing an error? Updating the wrong label? Updating the right label with the wrong text? Something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley I just couldn't get the labels to update, I spent a few hours trying to figure it out, and couldn't understand what I was doing wrong. It was throwing errors, but none of them really made sense to me. I'll try the below answer and see if that works. Thanks for your nice comments :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have two instances of `Tk()`: `root` and `app` (`pinger`).  StringVar `iWidth` and `iHeight` are within `root` scope, other widgets are within `app` scope.  So the content of the StringVars are not shown in widgets within `app`.

You can remove `root` stuff and only have `app` as the only instance of `Tk()`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image

class pinger(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):        
        self.iWidth = tk.StringVar()
        self.iHeight = tk.StringVar()

        # row 1
        labelDisclaim = tk.Label(self, text='Currently only works with jpegs')
        labelDisclaim.grid(column=2, row=1)

        # row 2
        labelWidth = tk.Label(self, text='Enter the width of the grid, in pixels.')
        labelWidth.grid(column=4,row=2)

        buttonOpen = tk.Button(self, text="Select an Image", command=self.openExplorer)
        buttonOpen.grid(column=2, row=2)

        # row 3
        labelStaticImg= tk.Label(self, text="Width of image, in pixels: ")
        labelStaticImg.grid(column=1,row=3)

        labelImgWidth = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.iWidth)
        labelImgWidth.grid(column=2,row=3)

        labelStaticHeight= tk.Label(self, text="Height of image, in pixels: ")
        labelStaticHeight.grid(column=3,row=3)

        labelImgHeight = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.iHeight)
        labelImgHeight.grid(column=4,row=3)

        # row 9
        button = tk.Button(self,text="exit",command=self.closeProgram)
        button.grid(column=3,row=9)

        # row 10
        labelSig = tk.Label(self, text='By Johnathan Keith, 2020. Ver 1.0')
        labelSig.grid(column=3,row=10)

    def openFile(self, imagefilename):
        Img = Image.open(imagefilename)
        height, width = Img.size
        self.iHeight.set(height)
        self.iWidth.set(width)

    def closeProgram(self):
        self.destroy()

    def openExplorer(self):
        filename= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select an Image", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"),("all files", "*.*")))
        if filename:
           print(filename)
           self.openFile(filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = pinger()
    app.title('Image Gridder')
    app.minsize(height=680,width=480)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting my spaghetti code, appreciate it. I'll test it out in the morning hopefully!